# How to insert created_timestamp in MongoDB using its Java Driver for Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mirth

I'm trying to use `$setOnInsert` using javascript, so I can insert the created_timestamp just the first time it hits Mongo.

```
var uri = new Packages.com.mongodb.MongoClientURI("mongodb://usr:pwd@localhost:27017/admin");
var mongoClient = new Packages.com.mongodb.MongoClient(uri);
var database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
var collection = database.getCollection("mycollection");
var curdate = DateUtil.getCurrentDate('yyyy-MM-dd');
var jsonDoc = JSON.stringify( 
    {       "unique_id": uid  //comes from a var from other part of the code
            "user" : {
            "id": id,
            "first": first,
            "last": last,   
            $setOnInsert: {"created_timestamp": curdate},
            "modified_timestamp": curdate
    }
);
var doc = Packages.org.bson.Document.parse(jsonDoc);
var comp = Packages.org.bson.Document.parse(JSON.stringify({"unique_id": idd}));
collection.replaceOne(comp, doc, (new com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions().upsert(true)));  
mongoClient.close();
```

And I'm receiving always a message that says that `$setOnInsert` is an invalid BSON field. What should I do?

BTW, I'm doing this javascript in Mirth. And already have its JARs, they are working fine when I'm just inserting documents. But I've been having this problem when I want to create the timestamp.

**UPDATE**

When I'm trying to use `updateOne()`, instead of `replaceOne()` Mirth gives me this error:

> LINE NUMBER:  2030 DETAILS:   Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Invalid BSON field name unique_id

When using this line:

```
collection.updateOne(comp, doc, (new com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions().upsert(true)));   
//line 2030
```

Even using Update, I don't know how should I use the setOnInsert function from this [driver](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html#setOnInsert-java.lang.String-TItem-). Sincerelly, I'm not good when it comes to javascript.

Comment: Hey @dnickless, thanks for commenting back. I'm using replaceOne() because for some reason it doesn't recognize updateOne() for me. I'll update my question with that.

Comment: I just deleted my previous comment since it was simply wrong. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `replaceOne()` does not support `$setOnInsert`.

And am uncertain as to how the precise Mirth syntax should look like and I do not have an environment to try it out. However, in raw MongoDB syntax, what you want to get is something like this:

```
collection.update(
{
    "unique_id": idd
    // add any other field here that makes up your filter
},
{
    $set: { "unique_id": uid },
    $set: { "user": { "id": id, "first": first, "last": last } },
    // add any other field to set as part of the update
    $setOnInsert: {"created_timestamp": new Date()}
}, {
    upsert: true
})
```

I hope this helps a little.

**Update:**

I would suggest you try passing the following instance to your updateOne command as the second parameter:

```
Document doc = new Document("unique_id", uid)
                .append("user", new Document("first", first).append("last", last))
                .append("$setOnInsert", new Document("created_timestamp": curdate));
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not having trouble with MongoDB syntax, since is pretty easy to understand. The thing is, I can't use Mongo's syntax in javascript if I'm using its Java driver. I just can't figure out how to do it using the Java driver.

Comment: What I need in other words is the correct way to tell BSON to recognize `$set` or `$setOnInsert`

Comment: I made it to work with update. Seems you were right since your first comment. It was sending me that error of `unique_id` because I didn't write in the JSON the `$set` statement before. It was waiting to be telled wich action is going to be used.

Comment: Glad to hear, sounds very likely.